# pytest fixture runs for class instead of each tests separately

Tags: python, testing, scope, pytest, fixtures

Could you explain to me please why fixture with scope function(which is supposed to run anew for each test) runs for the whole test class?

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def application_with_assigned_task_id(api, db, application_with_tasks_id, set_user_with_st_types):
    with allure.step("ищу задание по по id заявки"):
        task = \
            api.grpc.express_shipping.list_tasks(page_size=100, page_number=1, eams_id=application_with_tasks_id)[
                'tasks'][
                0]
        task_id = task["id"]
    with allure.step("назначаю задания на пользователя"):
        db.rezon.upd_user_warehouse(set_user_with_st_types, 172873)
        db.rezon.storetask_upd_user(task_id, set_user_with_st_types)
    with allure.step("проверяю назначение задания"):
        res = api.grpc.express_shipping.get_task(id=int(task_id))
        assert res["storekeeper"] == db.rezon.get_rezon_user_full_name_by_id(set_user_with_st_types)
    return application_with_tasks_id
```

application_with_tasks_id fixture has function scope as well, set_user_with_st_types has session scope(which I do not wish to change) What can I do?

I tried setting the scope specifically, even though I thought it normal for the fixture to run for each test anew by default
Setting the scope did not work

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Is the fixture not executing for every test? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

This simple example shows clearly that the tests are executed for each function and that's all (the output file will contain two lines). If it is not the case for you, please follow hoefling's comment and create a reproducible example (your code is both not complete and contains too many irrelevant things).

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture # (scope="function") is the default
def setup():
    f = open("/tmp/log", "a")
    print("One setup", file=f)
    f.close()
    
def test_one(setup):
    assert True

def test_two(setup):
    assert True
```